# Define WebSocket as a global in ES Lint for a React Native app

Tags: javascript, websocket, react-native, eslint

I get the following eslint error:

```
42:21  error  'WebSocket' is not defined  no-undef
```

You cannot import WebSocket from `react-native` because it's a global, but when I add WebSocket as globals to my `.eslintrc.yml` it doesn't change the outcome of the error:

```
globals:
   WebSocket: true
```

How do I define WebSocket as a global in ES Lint for a React Native app?

Can this be fixed? Currently my .eslintrc looks like this:

```
env:
  browser: false
  es6: true
  commonjs: true
  node: true
extends: 'airbnb'
parser: babel-eslint
globals:
    WebSocket: true
parserOptions:
  ecmaFeatures:
    experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
    jsx: true
  sourceType: module
plugins:
  - react
  - react-native
rules:
  indent:
    - error
    - tab
    - {"SwitchCase": 1}
  linebreak-style:
    - error
    - unix
  quotes:
    - error
    - double
  semi:
    - error
    - never
  no-tabs: off
  max-len: off
  no-console: off
  no-plusplus: off
  global-require: off
  import/no-unresolved: off
  import/extensions: off
  class-methods-use-this: off
  react/jsx-no-bind: off
  react/forbid-prop-types: off
  react/prefer-stateless-function: off
  react/jsx-indent: [2, 'tab']
  react/jsx-indent-props: [2, 'tab']
  react/jsx-filename-extension: [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }]
  react/jsx-uses-react: error
  react/jsx-uses-vars: error
  react-native/no-unused-styles: 2
  react-native/split-platform-components: 2
  react-native/no-inline-styles: off
  react-native/no-color-literals: off
```

I can get rid of it using the inline comment

```
/* globals WebSocket:true */
```

Also when I don't inherit from the airbnb eslint, but I can't figure out which lint rule in Airbnb is responsible for blocking this.

Comment: How are you running eslint? Also are you sure your `.eslintrc.yml` file is being used when running eslint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, it looks like your config file is not being picked up for some reason. Configuration for `globals` looks correct and should work. In order to figure out what is going on, you should do two things. First you can run `eslint --print-config path_to_some_js_file` to see how your config looks like after ESLint resolves all dependencies and cascading. Most likely that config will not have `globals` declared. After that, you can run `eslint --debug path_to_file` to see all config files that are being used by ESLint. If your file is not being included, check all other config files and verify that they don't have `root: true` in them (which would prevent ESLint from merging configs in parent directories). For more information about CLI flags you can look at [ESLint documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)